# Extracting residuals of maxent model in R?

Tags: r, maxent

I used "dismo" package in R, and ran a build a maxent model. Now I want to extract the residuals from the model in order to run a Moran I test later. But I got an error. 
The code was like:

```
xm<-maxent(pridictors, p=sdmdata, factors="landuse")
sdmresiduals<-cbind(sdmdata,resid(xm))
```

And the error appearred:

```
Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class
```

I don't understand what S4 class is. When I tried to have a look at the correlation between variables, using "car" package in R

```
vif(xm)
```

The same error happened.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This makes no sense, MaxEnt does not return residuals as it is nonparametric in nature.

Answer (score 1):

Only half an answer: `maxent()` returns an object of the class `MaxEnt`. The fact that this is an S4-type object doesn't matter much here, but if you want top know more about that you can read on [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html). The actual "problem" is that the `MaxEnt` class does not provide a method for the generic `residuals()` function (`resid()` is just a shortcut for `residuals()`). I other words: `resid()` does not know what to do with `xm`.

`resid(xm)` is probably looking for `xm$residuals`, but that does not exist because `MaxEnt` objects do not contain a `$residuals` slot. In fact, `MaxEnt` objects do not contain any residuals at all, so if you want them you'll have to calculate them youself somehow.